# Reducing integral

Tags: special-functions, elliptic-integrals

let $$I=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{mx^3-x^2+n}}$$
How do we reduce $I$ to an elliptic Integral of the first Kind ? where $m,n>0$ are constants.

Comment: there is an ugly solution

Comment: First, compute the roots $a,b,c$ of the equation $mx^3-x^2+n=0$. Then write the integral on the form $I=\frac{1}{sqrt m}\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)}}$. The result is a little bit less ungly : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2Fsqrt%28%28x-a%29%28x-b%29%28x-c%29%29 . Are you sure that you need to know the exlicit solution to answer to the problem ? What exactly is the original wording of the problem ?

Comment: I need this integral to describe motion of light ray in a centrally symmetric gravitational field, and I want to write general solution in the term of an elliptic Integral of the first Kind.

Comment: @vito Are the limits of integration known? Also, is anything else known about the constants $m$ and $n$ (e.g., are they integers)?